# Greater PHP version required

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have bought a new hosting plan and trying to install WordPress from the beginning. I am new with the installer I am using now. The error I get is unusual for me and i cant manage this problem. Should I wait my host feedback or I could solve it by myself?
[image]

I think i need to update PHP version but I do not know HOW to...

Comment: This seems to be off topic as defined here [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply buying some web hosting space (as opposed to a dedicated server of some kind, including a VPS), which version of PHP (if indeed any) is installed is out of your control.

If you are using a dedicated server, VPS or similar, and need to ask this kind of question, you should reconsider whether such hosting solutions are appropriate in your situation. Running an Internet-facing server is a large responsibility, not to be undertaken lightly.

Bottom line, assuming you aren't running your own server or server instance, **you will need to contact your web host's technical support department about this problem.** If they cannot answer the question, they will have the ability to escalate it internally to someone who can.